# How to create following type of json that will usefull in type ahead with angular js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typeahead, angular-ui-typeahead

I have successfully implement type ahead using angular js using this [`codepen`](http://codepen.io/joe-watkins/pen/EagEWv).

Now my data is dynamic so I want to create my own json that should looks something like following:

```
$scope.states = [
      {
          name: "ABCD",
          id: "AB"
      },
      {
          name: "XYZ",
          id: "XY"
      },
      {
          name: "OPQR",
          id: "OP"
      },
      {
          name: "LMNO",
          id: "LM"
      },
      {
          name: "KLM",
          id: "KL"
      }
    ];
```

How to create like above json and store in $scope variable so I can access it using name and id separately.

Please help me...!!

Comment: I don't think so sarath but anyway I got my answer thanks for comment sarathji.

Comment: #pedant: that is a javascript object, but it is not JSON

Comment: Ohhh yes it is my bad. Yes it is javascript object , isn't it consider as json?

Comment: To be valid JSON you would need to encapsulate all the parameters in `""` also. i.e. `{"name": "KLM"}`

Comment: Ohk now I see so what would I call the variable that consist data like name: "data1" type of content? and declare it like var states = [];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am giving by my own now cause I got it little bit late.

Solution is I have pushed the data wrong I have solved it like:

```
$scope.states.push({
                        name: "string",
                        id: int,
                    });
```

and I got it.